# Finding flux across surface

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let S be surface {$(x,y,z) : x^{2} + y^{2} + 2z =2 . z \geq 0 $}

Given F = $(y,xz,x^{2}+y^{2})$

n is outward normal .I have to find net flux through S .

Since its closed surface so i applied Gauss Divergence Theorem which yiels answer $0$ .But textbokk states andwer $2 \pi$ .Is their something i am missing ?

Comment: That's not a closed surface.

Comment: @MarkFantini why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a paraboloid. Isolate $z$; you will get $$z = 1 - \frac{x^2+y^2}{2}.$$ For $z \geq 0$ you have $$x^2+y^2 \leq 2.$$ To apply the divergence theorem you need to add the disk $z=0$, $x^2+y^2 \leq 2$. After this, find the flux across this disk and remove it from the total flux to find the flux across the paraboloid.

Comment: But doesn't z =0 (given in S) includes disk ?

Comment: @tomb_raider No, for if $z=0$ then $x^2+y^2=2$, not $x^2+y^2 \leq 2$. If you make $z=0$ you get the boundary of the disk.